# String passed into function is getting 'Object has no attribute' when split method is used

Tags: python-2.7

Taking a intro to python course, essentially what we have to do is ask the user for a number and then ask for a list of cities they'd like to visit based on that number. Then we have to print it and then print it again with the number adjusted by one. 
Trying to check my code as I write it but I'm having an issue making a listed out of the string I am passing to PrintAddOneCityNumSentence I keep getting AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'

Any help would be greatly appreciated 
Thanks

```
def MainFunction():
    number_cities = raw_input('How many cities would you like to list?,please use whole numeric values')
    user_number = AskForNumberCities(number_cities)
    user_city_list = AskForCityName(user_number)
    first_print = PrintFirstCitySentence(user_city_list)
    print first_print
    second_print = PrintAddOneCityNumSentence(first_print)
    print second_print



def AskForNumberCities(number_cities):
    try:
        int_number_cities = int(number_cities)
    except:
        ValueError
        print("Come on WHOLE NUMBERS!")
    else:
        print "Ok we can work with", int_number_cities ,"!"
    return int_number_cities


def AskForCityName(number):
    int_number = int(number)
    CityNameList = []
    while len(CityNameList) != int_number:
        for i in range(int_number):
            NewCityName = raw_input("Ok give me a city name")
            if NewCityName in CityNameList:
                print ("You already used that :/")
                continue
            else:
                CityNameList.append(NewCityName)
    else:
        return CityNameList
        print CityNameList

**def PrintFirstCitySentence(city_list):
    print_city_list = city_list
    x = 1
    print 'You would like to visit',
    for i in range(len(print_city_list)):**
        n = x + i
        print print_city_list[i],
        print 'as city',n,
    print ' on your trip'

def PrintAddOneCityNumSentence(first_print):
    first_print_list = first_print.split()
    for i in range(len(first_print_list)):
        if i.isdigit():
            i.append(i+1)





MainFunction()


None
  File "/Users/python_class/PycharmProjects/homework4/homework4.py", line 60, in <module>
    MainFunction()
  File "/Users/python_class/PycharmProjects/homework4/homework4.py", line 9, in MainFunction
    second_print = PrintAddOneCityNumSentence(first_print)
  File "/Users/python_class/PycharmProjects/homework4/homework4.py", line 51, in PrintAddOneCityNumSentence
    first_print_list = first_print.split()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Comment: `first_print` is assigned in your main function to the result of `PrintFirstCitySentence`. But `PrintFirstCitySentence` doesn't return, and therefore implicitly returns `None`, to which thus `first_print` gets assigned.

Comment: Can you put a comment in where the error is occurring?

Comment: @roelofs (and OP): better to post the full traceback.